# Remove list extensions button from chrome and display extension buttons directly

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I don't know how to search for this problem even on Google, So, I ended up asking it on stackoverflow

My Chrome is like this..

[image]

When I click on this **>>** button I get all the extensions like this..

[image]

I want all those extensions in my navigation bar itself. Means I don't want that **>>** button.

update - I am using Version 31.0.1650.63

Comment: What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: I have added version in my question

Comment: @Senthilmurugan found the answer. I have added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot I found the answer.

There is one expand icon ( `<->` ) which comes on hover just left of this `>>` button. When we click on that and expand to the left the extension icons start appearing in the navigation bar.